Data processing inequality for Fisher information
Let $\mathbf X=(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ be a random sample from some distribution $F_X(x;\theta)$ parameterized by a one dimensional parameter $\theta$ and let $T(\mathbf X)$ by any statistic of the random sample.
From the post here, we can decompose the Fisher information into
$$
I_\mathbf X(\theta)=I_{T(\mathbf X)}(\theta)+I_{\mathbf X|T(\mathbf X)}(\theta).
$$
Since the information in this case is a positive scalar we have
$$
I_{T(\mathbf X)}(\theta)=I_\mathbf X(\theta)-I_{\mathbf X|T(\mathbf X)}(\theta)\implies I_{T(\mathbf X)}(\theta)\leq I_\mathbf X(\theta)
$$
with equality if $T(\mathbf X)$ is a sufficient statistic.
How does such an inequality generalize for and $m$-dimensional parameter $\theta$?
For example, suppose $\theta=(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_m)$ is $m$-dimensional and $T(\mathbf X)$ is an $\ell$-dimensional statistic $(\ell\leq m)$.  In this case the information is an $m\times m$ matrix. How would we interpret the inequality sign in
$$
I_{T(\mathbf X)}(\theta)\leq I_\mathbf X(\theta)?
$$
Would this mean $I_\mathbf X-I_{T(\mathbf X)}$ is positive semidefinite?

I think it means that $I_{\mathbf{X}}(\theta)-I_{T(\mathbf{X})}(\theta)$ is a nonnegative definite matrix.

Actually, it should be written as
$$I_{\mathbf{X}}(\theta)=I_{T(\mathbf{X})}(\theta) + \mathbb{E}\left\lbrace I_{X\mid T(\mathbf{X})} \left[ \theta\mid T(\mathbf{X}) \right]  \right\rbrace .
$$
Since $I_{X\mid T(\mathbf{X})} \left[ \theta\mid T(\mathbf{X}) \right] $ is a conditional variance, it is nonnegative definite given any $ T(\mathbf{X}) $. Thus its expectation is also nonnegative definite.
